# Finding the domain of $f (x, y) = \ln (7 x^2 + 2 y + 1)$

Tags: calculus, functions, partial-derivative, several-complex-variables

> Find the domain of the function  $f(x,y) = \ln(7x^2 + 2y + 1)$.

I know that I should keep Domain Convention in mind when solving this question. I know that I can’t take the logarithm of a negative number or zero. It should be

$\frac{1 + 7x^2}{2}$

But I don't know how to determine whether it is $<,>$, or $\leq$, or $\geq$. I could really use the help please.

Comment: The answer to a question about a **domain** cannot be an algebraic expression. It must be a set.

Comment: What do you mean by "It should be $ \frac{1+7x^2}{2}$"? What should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the argument of the logarithm has to be positive. Thus, the domain is all coordinate pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying,

$$7x^2+2y+1 > 0.$$

Rearranging so $y$ is on one side, the above inequality is equivalent to,

$$y > -\frac{7x^2+1}{2}.$$

Thus, the domain is,

$$\left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y > -\frac{7x^2+1}{2}\right\}.$$

Comment: Not to nitpick but to avoid confusion, I would replace _"the logarithm has to be positive"_ by _"the **argument of the** logarithm has to be positive"_. The logarithm itself can be negative (and in fact will be negative, when its argument lies between 0 and 1).

Comment: @StackTD Thanks for bringing that up, I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: You're welcome; +1 for the answer.